# No such entity with orderId =

Tags: magento2, php, orders, api, no-such-entity-exception

I am using Webkul's extension for multiple vendors and I want to make an REST API endpoint where a vendor will be able to confirm the payment on a specific order. Everything works well until I try to save the order with `$order->save()` and I get the following error:

```
{
    "message": "No such entity with %fieldName = %fieldValue",
    "parameters": {
        "fieldName": "orderId",
        "fieldValue": "2"
    }
}
```

When saving an order with class  `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Interceptor` I keep getting the same error no matter what. 
I get the token using `/V1/integration/customer/token` endpoint.

P.S. If I get the token as admin `/V1/integration/admin/token`, everything seems to work fine.

Any thoughts?

Comment: can you share the request url & params?

Comment: The request URL is my own `/default/V1/orders/1/confirm` and needs the Bearer token which I pass in the body. But this part works because I can get the seller id from the session.